# Two GPIO buttons calling the same object

Tags: python, object, button, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am working with a Pi3, a bread board, a temp sensor and a 4-channel relay. Right now, I have two buttons on my bread board, which, when pushed are supposed to display the temperature and turn on a relay and turn of another. I am working towards building a smart thermostat so think of the buttons representing air-conditioning and heating, they cannot be on at the same time.

My issue is that, when displaying the temperature, it references the object (read_temp()), which displays the temperature correctly for one button and not the other. It will only display the very last part of equation which converts Celsius to Fahrenheit. For example, I will hit both buttons, one will display 75 degrees and the other will always display 32.

I have tried declaring the buttons differently as GPIO.inputs, I have moved to different GPIO pins thinking it is a hardware issue, I have switched the position of the buttons and I have tried returning both temp_c and temp_f in (read_temp()) object and nothing seems to do the trick.

Currently, it is the AC button that is not working properly but as I mentioned, I have switched the buttons and the pins around and it still only displays properly for one.

Thanks!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import glob
import time
import sys
from gpiozero import Button
import pdb



# init list with pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pinList = [2, 3, 27, 17]
AC = Button(12)
Heat = Button(21)

# loop through pins and set mode and state to 'high'

for i in pinList: 
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT) 
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)


# time to sleep between operations in the main loop

##SleepTimeL = 5

# Setting up temperarture sensor
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_f 


# main loop
try:
    while True:
        if AC.is_pressed:
            GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
            print(read_temp()), "degrees farenheit"

        if Heat.is_pressed:
            GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
            print(read_temp()), "degrees farenheit"

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "  Quit"

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I cant see the reason why pressing one button would return a different temp from the other. Have you tried debugging the value of "lines" or "temp_string" ? Basically look for reasons why temp_c would give you a zero value.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried debugging that and have not had much luck. To be honest though, I am relatively new to the python debugger so I'l try and give it another shot. Thanks!